# Any source for this formula?

Tags: percentages, online-resources

I have never learned math through English as a medium of instruction, so my English math vocabulary is very poor.

My problem: I had some data for different neighborhoods. For example:

```
Neighborhood A: 10 square miles
Neighborhood B: 8 square miles
Neighborhood C: 7 square miles
```

What I needed to do is express these values in a 0 to 100 range. So, I thought about it and I came up with this formula:

[image]

```
v – value in the 0 to 100 range
n – given value
max – maximum value of the input range
min – minimum value of input range
```

I think this is the correct formula to represent the data under an even range. The problem is the professor (a geography professor) is asking why I chose this formula. Moreover, he is asking for a source. Anyone knows how this formula is called and what source to use for it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this formula has a name. One can however prove it does what you wanted.

You just need to prove that $\frac{n-\min}{\max-\min}$ sends all the values correctly on $[0,1]$ since after you're multiplying by $100$.

The formula is equivalent to $n=x(\max-\min)+\min$ where $x$ is the new value in $[0,1]$.

$x(\max-\min)$ gives the distance between $x$ and $\min$ (for instance if $x=0.5$,$x(\max-\min)$ is half the length of the interval)

Adding $\min$ offsets $x$ so that it starts at the right point.

Comment: Correct. Your equation is the same as $n = x(\max)+(1-x)(\min)$. One can then verify all values of $n$ are less than max, and greater than min for all $x \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you rationalize it. We want a curve that represents your data from $0..100$ so lets use a straight line first.
$$
y = md + C
$$
$y$ is the representation of the distance on the $0..100$ scale, $m$ is the gradient, $d$ is the distance you want to scale, and $C$ is the intercept.

so in particular, we want the points to be defined as the following 
$$
(d_{\text{min}},0),\\
(d_{\text{max}},100)
$$
thus we have
$$
0 = md_{\text{min}} + C\\
100 = md_{\text{max}} + C\\
$$
you have a simultaneous equation for $m,C$.
thus we get
$$
100-0 = md_{\text{max}} - md_{\text{min}} = m\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)
$$
this leads to
$$
m = \frac{100}{\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)}
$$
now lets find the intercept
$$
md_{\text{min}} +C = \frac{100}{\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)}d_{\text{min}}  + C = 0
$$
thus
$$
C = -\frac{100}{\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)}d_{\text{min}}
$$
thus we get
$$
y = \frac{100}{\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)}x -\frac{100}{\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)}d_{\text{min}} = \frac{x-d_{\text{min}}}{\left(d_{\text{max}} -d_{\text{min}}\right)}100
$$
note, $x$=$n$

Comment: @Ardit i suggestion to Add to the explanation of Chinny84 a graph to your prof a  line and place on it your points together with min and max points

Comment: @Idris, I am documenting the formula in a research report, so I don't think it is a good idea to set the focus on graphical explanations of the formula in the report. The problem is more about how to make the professor happy and provide a source of the formula.

Comment: @Chinny84, great flow, but a professor of geography would prefer a source to get convinced that the formula is right, rather than a "bunch" of other formulas. "Bunch" in the perspective of someone who is not good at math.

Comment: Equation of a line given two points. Search for references of that. It is basic geometry :/ (not using the word basic in a derogatory fashion).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understand what you are looking for; an ''accepted'' formula which transforms values of some set of
data into others data ranking between 0 and 100 and which preserves the ranking
of the initial data. If it is so, then I suggest to you another formula
rather then that you did find which gives the same output for the same
input. However this formula is largely documented in statistics books. It is
related to the percentile (in descriptive statistics).

First, you should know that your input is the value of the data, say $n$, in
your notation and the output is in your notation, the $v$-th percentile (but
in statistics books, it is called the $P$-th percentile). The well known
formula is
$$ the\ ordinal\  rank\ of\ a\ data=\frac{its\ P^{th}-percentile}{100}%
\times the\ number\ of\ data
$$
which may be found in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile. From this
formula you can deduce that
$$%
the\ P^{th}-percentile\ of\ a\ data=\frac{the\ ordinal\ rank\ of\ a\
data}{the\ number\ of\ data}\times 100.
%$$
which in your notation reads as follows

$$
v=\frac{the\ ordinal\ rank\ of\ n}{the\ number\ of\ data}\times 100.
$$
You can use this last formula since it provides the same output as yours for the same
input. In fact $$
\frac{the\ ordinal\ rank\ of\ n}{the\ number\ of\ data}=\frac{n-\min 
}{\max -\min }.
$$
EDIT: Actually, I have used the formula
$$
n=\left( \frac{P}{100}\times N\right) 
$$
instead of 
$$
n=\left\lceil \frac{P}{100}\times N\right\rceil .
$$ since when rounding off your computations, it leads to almost the same numbers.